# Кодировка в Python, библиотека Pymorhpy

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

Сейчас появилась необходимость использование морфологического анализатора. Я выбрал pymorphy, но вот что-то у меня не лады с кодировкой, вот пример:
Python
Выделить код

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pymorphy import get_morph
morph = get_morph('/home/anton/Downloads/ru.sqlite-json')
word = u'КРАНАМ'
print morph.normalize(word)
```

Метод normalize должен вернуть нормальную форму переданного ему слова
Но вот что я получаю на выходе:

```
[u'\u041a\u0420\u0410\u041d']
```

Как мне подсказали онлйан декодеры, это и есть слово "КРАН", то есть то что мне нужно. Но как бы мне выводить в более человеческом виде?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How to prevent str to encode unicode characters as hex codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33723821/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С кодировкой у вас всё нормально. Вы получаете правильный ответ. Проблема в том как вы его отображаете.

`morph.normalize(word)` возвращает список с одной строкой внутри (`[u"КРАН"]`). Если напечатать список, то к каждому элементу списка применяется `repr(item)` функция, которая экранирует все непечатаемые (вне `0x20..0x7e` диапазона—всё что не является `printing character` + `" "` в С) символы с помощью `\uXXXX` и подобных последовательностей.

Чтобы получить `КРАН`, печатайте Unicode строки напрямую:

```
print "\n".join(morph.normalize(word))
```